# How can I know whether permission for Push notification is activated or not in service worker?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I'm working on a progressive web app(PWA) project which makes push notification in service worker. It's successful to make a push notification with FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging), but I'm wondering how I know whether my web app has a permission for push notification from user's browser or not. If it's possible, I want to show user button to request permission for push notification. Is it possible?

Comment: Isn't using `messaging.requestPermission()` for this exact scenario?

Comment: It's rather requesting permission. In this case, I want to know whether notification is permitted by browser before requesting permission. Actually I solved this problem with this code like `navigator.serviceWorker.register(swUrl).then(registration => { firebase.messaging().useServiceWorker(registration); registration.pushManager.getSubscription().then(subscription => { ... }) })`.

Comment: In this code, `firebase` is connected `service worker`, so if firebase gets permission, it's registered in service worker's `subscription` that I can check from the service worker whether browser has the permission.

Answer (score 7):

You can check to see if your site can send push messages and display notifications use [Notification.permission](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/permission).

```
if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
  // Push notification permission granted.
}
```